# How to share image in angular js social share in facebook

Tags: angularjs, socialshare

I need to share the image in Angular js social share for Facebook. But it doesn't show the image in sharing.
Here is my Code.

```
<button class="btn btn-info"
    socialshare
    socialshare-provider="facebook"
    socialshare-type="feed"
    socialshare-via="MY KEY"
    socialshare-quote="Thiscountz quote"
    socialshare-display="page"
    socialshare-quote="Thiscountz quote"
    socialshare-url="thiscountz.com" 
    socialshare-media="https://static.ipictheaters.com/2011102503/cache/Content/images/marketing/herocrop.jpg">

    <span class="fa fa-facebook "></span>

</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the images url to `social-media` and you should use **`socialshare-url`** for facebook. If you read the [docs](https://github.com/720kb/angular-socialshare#facebook), you will see that `social-media` is not part of facebook share directives/options.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info"
    socialshare
    socialshare-provider="facebook"
    socialshare-type="feed"
    socialshare-via="MY KEY"
    socialshare-quote="Thiscountz quote"
    socialshare-display="page"
    socialshare-url="https://static.ipictheaters.com/2011102503/cache/Content/images/marketing/herocrop.jpg" >

    <span class="fa fa-facebook "></span>

</button>
```

---

*Also, I've noted that you are setting the `socialshare-quote` option twice, and you didn't add a `type="button"` to the button (Maybe this isn't related with your real problem, but you can add the button type as a good practice)*

Comment: I could provide to you a plunker if you still have problems. Good luck!!!